# Select records from a table only where a field value is repeated less than x times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL and I would appreciate it if you could help me. I have a table that has a field with many IDs and that field is in number format. The same ID may repeat different number of times, e.g. 5 times, 6 times. I want to display records of **all fields** only when the same ID is repeated less than x times in this field. Which sql statement will get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM TableName T1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ID,COUNT(ID) as Count
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) < 5) T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
```

**EDIT:**

Try your query using alias names:

```
SELECT APropertyID,BPropertyID,Ayy,Byy from 
(SELECT a.PropertyID as APropertyID, b.PropertyID as BPropertyID, a.yy as Ayy,b.yy  as Byy
FROM tableA a full outer join 
     tableB b on a.PropertyID=b.PropertyID ) a1 
inner join 
(SELECT PropertyID,COUNT(PropertyID) as Count 
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY PropertyID 
HAVING COUNT(PropertyID) < 5) c 
on a1.APropertyID=c.PropertyID
```

Comment: Yakshemash ! I am not sure why you used a `JOIN`. This works for me `select id, COUNT(id) as cnt
from TableName
group by id
having COUNT(id) < 3` Am I missing something ? Chenqui.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev: I agree with that, my friend. That was my first answer though. Your query will get only the `id`s. But OP is asking for **all fields** in the table. That is why I used a join.

Comment: Thanks Raging Bull, 
my case is a bit more complicate where i already have a joint table like below so when i combine it like you suggested i cannot seem to get it right. may i have your help on what went wrong here?

SELECT * from (SELECT a.PropertyID, b.PropertyID, a.yy,b.yy
FROM tableA a
full outer join tableB b on a.PropertyID=b.PropertyID 
 )  a1 
 
 
inner join (SELECT PropertyID,COUNT(PropertyID) as Count
FROM tableA
GROUP BY PropertyID
HAVING COUNT(PropertyID) < 5) c 
on a1.PropertyID=c.PropertyID

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows for an [OVER Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) in aggregates (which is a useful but "nonstandard" SQL feature) that is handy in cases like this.

> Determines the partitioning and ordering of a rowset before the associated window function is applied. That is, the OVER clause defines a window or user-specified set of rows within a query result set. A window function then computes a value for each row in the window. You can use the OVER clause with functions to compute aggregated values such as moving averages, cumulative aggregates, running totals, or a top N per group results.

Example:

```
SELECT cts.*
FROM (
    -- Build intermediate result where each record also has
    -- a count of how many times that value appears.
    SELECT
        t.*,
        COUNT (1) OVER (PARTITION BY value) as valueCount
    FROM t
) as cts
-- Filter intermediate result based on collected count.
WHERE cts.valueCount < 5
```

(I've used `value` instead of `ID` above - the same approach holds.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN
  (SELECT ID
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT(1) < 5)
```

Comment: Yakshemash ! I am not sure why you used a `JOIN`. This works for me `select id, COUNT(id) as cnt
from TableName
group by id
having COUNT(id) < 3` Am I missing something ? Chenqui.

Comment: I didn't use a join?  This is the simplest way to do what was wanted: "the purpose is to display records of all fields "

Comment: oops...just copy pasted my above comment without editing. my mistake.